# Can I get the current user in a model delete method (to delete the appropriate m2m through) in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, m2m

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
class Item(TimestampedModel):
    ....
    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # Other users have linked to this item, delete the link
        if UserItem.objects.filter(item=self).count() > 1:
            # TODO Delete the UserItem linking the current User to this Item

        # No one else has linked to this item, delete the item
        else:
            super(Item, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)

class UserItem(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item= models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Thats sort of thing (where the user is known) is usually done at the view level.

Comment: I thought as much, but was hoping to keep this delete logic in the model

Comment: You could hack the save method, passing in the user in kwargs and poping it before calling super, but you are still going to need to pass in the user from the views level.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to make sure that `Item` is not used by more than 1 user before deleting, then you can do something like this:

Add `related_name` for ease of use:

```
class UserItem(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item= models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, ralated_name='used_by')
```

And before on delete you can check like this:

```
if self.used_by.values('user').distinct().count() > 1:
   # THIS MEANS THERE ARE MORE THAN ONE USER LINKING TO THIS ITEM
else:
   super(Item, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

Though if you choose to implement this, then I assume only users who are "linked" to this item can delete it, so that no one can delete another's item.

Usually, it's better to do this kind of logic inside the view though (as @wobbily_col commented).

Answer (score 1):

A post-condition of `delete` should be that the model instance no longer exists in the database.

A conditional delete is a kind of business logic that lies between the view and the model.  And with that observation comes the benefit of your defining the name and the arguments of the function yourself.  Say `detach_item_from_user(item, user)`.

See also "Two Scoops of Django" under "Fat Models, Utility Modules, Thin Views, Stupid Templates".

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I went with. It keeps the logic in the `model`, but the `view` gives it the current `user`.

I thought it best to keep out of `delete()` because an admin user should be able to delete an Item regardless of related users, and there is no simple way to access the current `user` within `delete()`.

Constructive criticism welcome!

#### models.py

```
class Item(TimeStampedModel):

    ...

    def delete_item_or_user_item(self, user):
        """
        Delete the Item if the current User is the only User related to it.
        If multiple Users are related to the Item, delete the UserItem.
        """
        if UserItem.objects.filter(item=self).count() > 1:
            UserItem.objects.filter(item=self, user=user).delete()
        else:
            self.delete()
```

#### views.py

```
class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    ...

    def perform_destroy(self, instance):
        instance.delete_item_or_user_item(self.request.user)
```

Comment: How is this different from my answer (besides that you decided to change two out of three names)?

Comment: Code, which gives the solution context, showing how and where, and making it easier for the next person who needs an answer to this to get at the solution, because when I'm viewing someone else's question the answers with code are the ones I find most helpful.